# Animating elements by change class in Angular2+

Tags: css, angular

I need to add some animation to my Angular project, and best way I came up with is just make from classname a variable and switch it in .ts file(if I need to attach style to event for example). So that mean a have two(or more) css style sets to make an animation do what I want...

Questions is:

1) Is it bad in any other way than just a lot of css code? I mean I'm fine with that, just wanna know is other people do the same? Cause its feels a bit like nasty coding...

2) I heard about angular core animation, do I have to use it here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning classes works really well in angular, I actually prefer using CSS for animation rather than the angular libraries.

To assign classes on certain conditions, you can use the following notation in your template:

```
<div class="card" [class.card--inactive]="yourCondition">
```

This will add the class `card--inactive` to the div whenever `yourCondition` is true.

Comment: ow yeah, in that way I can add a new class to already existed! silly me... thanks!

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if I was able to solve your issue :)